# Using django-elasticsearch-dsl with AWS ElasticSearch - raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I'm trying to convert up a Django application using django-elasticsearch-dsl and a elasticsearch server to using AWS ElasticSearch which I am deploying using ElsaticBeanStalk

When I use

```
03_elasticsearch:   
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && ./src/manage.py search_index --rebuild -f"
```

I get this error

```
Creating index 'hjsm-local'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 134, in handle
  self._rebuild(models, options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 114, in _rebuild
  self._create(models, options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 84, in _create
  index.create()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/index.py", line 102, in create
  self.connection.indices.create(index=self._name, body=self.to_dict(), **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
  return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 110, in create
  params=params, body=body)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
  status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 110, in perform_request
  self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 114, in _raise_error
  raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
  elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: <exception str() failed>
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

I do not understand what this is telling me - can anyone advise?

**UPDATE**

I think I am getting an HTTP 406 error, but I do not understand why.  If I run locally using localhost:9200 rather than my aws eleasticsearch server, it works fine.

Comment: You might want to check if the version of django-elasticsearch-dsl you're using supports the version of AWS ES you're using

Comment: I've come t the same conclusion.  I think the current system is using elasticsearch2.4 (which is surprising because it is using django2.1).  I'm trying to find an elasticsearch service that provides 2.4 so I don't need to instigate it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was it needed ElasticSearch 2.4.  I have to setup a server with this running and when I connected through it worked!